# how to position items vertically in navbar

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap-based ASP.NET application, I need to show navigational links (Home, About, etc.) on the right of the navbar. I also need to have a search button below the nav links. The button must be right-aligned with the right-most nav link. Here is the code that I tried:

```
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 navbar-right">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" action="~/Home/Search">

                    <div class="input-group ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="term" name="term" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

However, the search button is still shown on the same row as the nav links.

How do I get items to vertically right-align in the navbar? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the form in a new container, see **[this demo](http://www.bootply.com/JcFBayQ82c)** (also, I made edits to the structure to correct it):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" method="get" action="~/Home/Search">
        <div class="input-group ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="term" name="term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```